# Date/time in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I had 1 data frames :

```
`Ticker /Date/Time  /Gia today`
`0  CTF /2/1/2020   /23.50`
`2  PXL /2/1/2020   /8.40`
`3  DBC /2/1/2020   /20.52`
`4  TCH /2/1/2020   /32.42`
`5  DRC /2/1/2020   /22.28`
`6  HSG /2/1/2020   /7.80`
`8  KOS /2/1/2020   /27.90`
`9  SBT /2/1/2020   /18.02`
`11 MPC /2/1/2020   /19.70`
`13 NKG /2/1/2020   /7.38`
`15 HPG /2/1/2020   /19.63`
```

I want to find: `d ='7/1/2020'`
I tried to use :

```
`date_string = '2/1/2020'`

`# Strptime`
`format = '%d/%m/%Y'`
`date_time_python = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format)` 
`d=date_time_python+timedelta(days = 4)`
```

but the value of d return is: `Jan 06, 2020`
How can I exclude the weekend on the code above to get d = '7/1/2020'`.

Comment: Well you are going to get Jan 6 if you're adding delta of 4 days to 2nd Jan

Comment: What is the exact output based on the data frame you showed above?

Comment: Don't use `datetime` package. Use `pd.to_datetime`: `pd.to_datetime('2/1/2020', dayfirst=True)`

Comment: @Suhas Mucherla, I know it. But I don't know how to exclude the weekend days to get '7/1/2020' from '2/1/2020'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay() instead of timedelta. I believe you have to subtract one from the number of business days, so you would use pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay(3) in your case.